# Visual Studio 2008 with Perforce plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 and I installed the Perforce plug -in

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/component.html

I went through install and rebooted system and now I want to
use in VS.  So I go to the Tools-->Options-->Source Control->Plug-in Selection

and the only choice I can select is 'None'.

What do I need to do to install

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with the newest version of Perforce and it worked fine for me.

[This is the link I downloaded the plugin from](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/perforce/r10.2/bin.ntx86/p4sccinst.exe).

Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/bin.ntx86

Get the file "**p4sccinst.exe**".  Install it.  Then from VS2008,

> File > source control > change source control and bind it to your p4
>   server.

The rest is pretty easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new tool for your wish called [P4VS](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/visual-studio-plug-in). I use it successfully for checking out and submitting files from within Visual Studio 2010.